# Unable to post from jQuery to nodejs endpoint

Tags: jquery, node.js

Unable to read form data pass in by jQuery in node.js

jQuery code in ejs:

```js
  var data1 = $('#form-horizontal1').serialize();
    $.ajax({
      url: "/users/home/dashboard",
      data: data1,
      dataType:'json',
      ContentType:'application/json',
      type: 'POST',
      success: function (result) {
          console.log(result);
          if(result.status == 200){
            console.log(result);
              //self.isEditMode(!self.isEditMode());
          }
      },
      error: function(result){
          console.log(result);
      }
  });
```

my form in ejs:

```html
 <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Enter Pincode</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="result">
        <p>Please request for the pincode from the customer.</p>
        <form class="form-horizontal" id="form-horizontal1" action="/users/home/dashboard" role="form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label  class="col-sm-2 control-label">Pincode:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" 
                name="pinCode" placeholder="Pincode from customer"/>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Confirm</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

node.js

```js
router.post('/home/dashboard',function(req,res,next){
  if(req.method === 'POST' && req.session.userId != null){
    var pinCode= req.body.data;
    pinCode = pinCode.slice(8);
    TransactionDetails.findOne({
      where: {
          //transaction_pincode:randomNumber,
          transaction_pincode:pinCode,
          transaction_verified:0
      }
```

`req.body` returns empty.

I am trying to pass in the data user input in the form to jquery to perform POST in node.js and return the success message back to jquery.

However, when I ran the code, `req.body` in node.js returns empty object. How can I fix this please ?

Comment: It's `contentType` (lower `c`) not `ContentType`

Comment: @Andreas changed that but req.body is still empty object

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `serialize()` you are in fact just passing an URL-encoded string on the form `pinCode=value` (separated by `&` if you have multiple inputs).

You must ensure you pass something to the express endpoint that can be parsed as JSON. You can use `serializeArray()` which creates a `{ name:pinCode, value:value }` dictionary and build up a parseable JSON string from that :

```js
var serialized = $('#form-horizontal1').serializeArray();
var params = {};
for (var param in serialized) {
   params[serialized[param].name] = serialized[param].value
}
params = JSON.stringify(params);
```

Now you have a string on the form

```js
'{ "pincode": "value" }'
```

Send it as

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "/users/home/dashboard",
  data: params,
  contentType: 'application/json',
  type: 'POST',
  ...
})
```

If everything else is right (and we must assume it is) you will now be able to access

```js
var pinCode = req.body.pinCode; //not 'data'
```

in your endpoint function

---

Obviously the above is meant as generic answer to automate form elements -> valid JSON. If you not have a complex form you can just use

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "/users/home/dashboard",
  data: JSON.stringify({ pinCode: $('input[name=pinCode]').val() } ),
  contentType: 'application/json',
  type: 'POST',
  ...
})
```